# If I Put In OpenEXR Frames For HDR Would I Be Able To Use Blender To Export The Video As HDR

Tags: video-sequence-editor

If I were to make 120 HDR Frames would I be able to use blender to export it as a HDR video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your EXRs are scene referred, and while Blender cannot encode to HDR10 or Dolby Vision, those EXRs are perfectly acceptable to encode to HDR via Resolve or like software.